# Is there any way I can create text inside a rectangle?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm quite new to Tkinter and I want to add text and a button inside a rectangle so that it will move along with the rectangle when I animate it.

I've tried researching on websites such as effbot.org and I can't seem to find the answer. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Are you asking about text on a canvas?

Comment: You can set the `tags` option of the `rectangle`, `text` and `button` items to same one, for example `'rect-group'`, and then use `canvas.move('rect-group', dx, dy)` to move them together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to add a button and a label to a canvas in `python3` using Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def clicked(event):
    print("pressed")

canvas1 = Canvas(root, relief = FLAT, background = "#D2D2D2")
canvas1.pack()
label = Label(root, text="Hello world")
label.pack()
buttonBG = canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 30, fill="grey40", outline="grey60")
buttonTXT = canvas1.create_text(50, 15, text="click")
canvas1.tag_bind(buttonBG, "<Button-1>", clicked) ## when the square is clicked runs function "clicked".
canvas1.tag_bind(buttonTXT, "<Button-1>", clicked) ## same, but for the text.
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a canvas, the simple solution is to create the text, get the coordinates, and then draw a rectangle based on those coordinates. If you use the same tag for both the text and rectangle then you can move them or configure them as one.

Here's a simple example:

```
def create_item(canvas, x, y, tag):
    tags = (tag,)
    button = tk.Button(canvas, text="x")
    canvas.create_text(50,100, text="Hello, world", fill="white", tags=tags)
    canvas.create_window(50,130, window=button, tags=tags)

    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(tag)
    margin = 4
    coords = (x0-margin, y0-margin, x1+margin, y1+margin)
    id=canvas.create_rectangle(coords, outline="white", fill="red", tags=tag)
    canvas.lower(id)
```

You can use it like this:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
...
create_item(10, 10, "item")
canvas.move("item", 1,1)
...
```